# Using DateTime and DateInterval functions in Twig

Tags: function, date, object, addition, twig

I have two objects in Twig:

1. `{{ date }}` is `DateTime` object
2. `{{ interval }}` is `DateInterval` object

I need to show date with interval added. How can I use `DateObject` php function like `add()` with this two objects? 
I can't do this on controller side, I need interval to date in twig. :(

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`date_modify`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/date_modify.html).

In your case, it would go as:

```
{{ yourDate|date_modify(yourInterval)|date("m/d/Y") }}
```

Comment: I had to use `{{ yourDate|date_modify(yourInterval|date("%H hours + %I minutes + %s seconds"))|date("m/d/Y") }}` but thank you very very much. :)